# Serializing a class with a pointer in C++

Tags: c++, serialization, pointers

I want to serialize an object of type `Person`. I want to use it later on for data saving or even game saving. I know how to do it for primitives like `int`, `char`, `bool`, and even c-strings like `char[]`.

The problem is, I want the string to be as big as it needs to rather than declaring a `char` array of size 256 and hoping no one enters something too big. I read that serializing a class with `std::string` as a member doesn't work because it has an internal pointer, but is there a way to serialize my class which has a `char*` as a member?

I realize Boost has a serialization library, but I'd like to do this without the need of external libraries, it seems like a good activity to try.

Here's my `Person` class:

```
class Person
{
private:
   char* _fname; 
   char* _lname;

public:
   Person();
   Person(const char* fname, const char* lname);
   Person(const string& fname, const string& lname);

   string fname() const;
   void fname(const char* fname);
   void fname(const string& fname);

   string lname() const;
   void lname(const char* lname);
   void lname(const string& lname);
};
```

Comment: Why do you have naked pointers in the first place? Do you like pain?

Comment: Well I would _love_ to use `std::string`, but I've been told that serializing a class with that as a member can be very tricky. `char` arrays would work too I suppose, but you have to know length at compile time.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help with matters of faith and belief, but if I were to talk to someone about C++ who I liked, I would try my best to make them use `std::string`.

Comment: Is it possible to accomplish serialization with `std::string` though, don't get me wrong, I _really_ want to use it, I like `std::string`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You should post *that* as a question! (Now we have a real XZ situation here :-).)

Comment: Proper serialization is hard; using a well-tested, well-documented external library e.g. Boost.Serialization is the _only sane option_.

Comment: Loki's answer was pretty sane to me... My classes aren't _that_ huge where I need a whole library. Besides, I like using standard language features myself, that way libraries don't look magical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: Use std::string in your class it will make your life so much easier in the long run.

But this advice works for both std::string and char* (with minor tweaks that should be obvious).

Basically you want to serialize data of unknown size (at compile time). This means when you de-serialize the data you must either have a technique that tells you how long the data is (prefix the object with a size) or a way to find the end of the data (a termination marker).

A termination marker is easier for serialization. But harder for de-serialization (as you must seek forward to find the end). Also you must escape any occurrences of the termination marker within your object and the de-serialization must know about the escaping and remove it.

Thus because of this complications I prefer not to use a termination marker. As a result I prefix the object with a size. The cost of this is that I must encode the size of the object in a way that will not break.

So if we prefix an object with its size you  can do this:

```
// Place a ':' between the string and the size.
// There must be a marker as >> will continue reading if
// fname contains a digit as its first character.
// I don;t like using a space as >> skips spaces if you are not carefull
// and it is hard to tell the start of the string if the first characters in fname
// are the space character.
std::cout << strlen(fname) << ":" << fname;
```

Then you can de-serialize like this:

```
size_t size;
char   mark;
std::cint >> size >> mark;
if (!std::cin || mark != ':')
{    throw BadDataException;
}
result = new char[size+1]();  // Note the () to zero fill the array.
std::cin.read(result, size)
```

#### Edit 1 (based on comments) Update: to use with string:

```
size_t size;
char   mark;
std::cint >> size >> mark;
if (!std::cin || mark != ':')
{    throw BadDataException;
}
std::string  result(' ', size);  // Initialize string with enough space.
std::cin.read(&result[0], size)  // Just read directly into the string
```

#### Edit 2 (based on commented)

Helper function to serialize a string

```
struct StringSerializer
{
    std::string&    value;
    StringSerializer(std::string const& v):value(const_cast<std::string&>(v)){}
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, StringSerializer const& data)
    {
        stream << data.value.size() << ':' << data.value;
    }
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, StringSerializer const& data)
    {
        std::size_t size;
        char        mark(' ');
        stream >> size >> mark;
        if (!stream || mark != ':')
        {    stream.setstate(std::ios::badbit);
             return stream;
        }
        data.value.resize(size);
        stream.read(&data.value[0], size);
    }
};
```

Serialize a Person

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, Person const& data)
{
    return stream << StringSerializer(data.fname) << " "
                  << StringSerializer(data.lname) << " "
                  << data.age                     << "\n";
}
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, Person& data)
{
    stream    >> StringSerializer(data.fname)
              >> StringSerializer(data.lname)
              >> data.age;
    std::string line;
    std::getline(stream, line);

    if (!line.empty())
    {    stream.setstate(std::ios::badbit);
    }
    return stream;
}
```

Usage:

```
int main()
{
    Person p;
    std::cin  >> p;
    std::cout << p;

    std::ofstream  f("data");
    f << p;
}
```

Comment: should `cin` and `cout` be replaced with `fstream` objects? And this is just a general question, when extracting `size` and `mark`, how does it know to read the number and the char? Are they represented differently in the file?

Comment: std::cin and std::cout are just examples of stream. They can be replaced by any other stream type object include std::fstream.

Comment: The stream objects look at they type of object they are streaming into/outof and do the correct thing. You need to separate objects in the stream with a space character so that >> operator know where each start/end. Note: `<size>:<string data>` is one object thus not space separated internally but should be space separated from other objects.

Comment: Amazing, It worked! And yeah, I'll use `std::string` instead. I'll just use `str.length()` instead of `strlen()` and create another `string` with the result like this: `string strResult(result)`. Thank you!

Comment: @rcplusplus: No don't do that. Make sure the string is the correct size then read directly into the string.

Comment: If I add a member variable `int _age` to my class, could I write the data members like this: `out << _fname << '\n' << _lname << '\n' << _age` and then read the data back with `getline()` like this: `getline(in, newFname, '\n'); getline(in, newLname, '\n'); getline(in, newAge, '\n')`?

Comment: @rcplusplus: You could (but that is like using the end marker (with '\n' as the marker I described above for strings). If your string contains a '\n' then you need to work out a way to escape the '\n' inside the string. Also your records are now spread over multiple lines making the hard to read. I like 1 record per line so I can read the data file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't serialize pointer, you need to serialize data pointer points to.

You'll need to serialize whole web of objects, starting from `Person` (or `Game`) and looking into each object, which is reachable from your start object.

When deserializing, you reading data from your storage, allocate memory for that data and use address of this freshly allocated memory as a member of `Person`/`Game` object

Comment: How do you serialize the data a `char*` points to? Forgive me for asking, I'm not too skilled in pointers, but doesn't dereferencing the pointer (like such `*_lname`) just return the first character?

Comment: In C `char*` is standard way to represent "string": `_lname` points to first character and string lasts until first zero byte is encountered. In C++ it's better to use `std::string` to represent "string", but you still need to get a pointer to first characted via `std::string::c_str()` when serializing.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer fields make it bit harder, but not impossible to serialize. If you don't want to use any of the serialization libraries, here is how you can do it.

You should determine the size of what is pointed to at the time of serialization (e.g. it may be of fixed size or it may be a C-string with null character at the end), then you can save a mark indicating that you're serializing an indirect object together with size and the actual content of the area pointed to.

When you stumble upon that mark during deserialization, you can allocate the right amount of memory, copy the object into it and store the pointer to the area in the deserialized object.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a vector to encapsulate strings for 
serialization.

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
map vector<unsigned char> cbuff;
inline cbuff vchFromString(const std::string &str) {
unsigned char *strbeg = (unsigned char*) str.c_str();
  return cbuff(strbeg, strbeg + str.size());
}
inline std::string stringFromVch(const cbuff &vch) {
 std::string res;
 std::vector<unsigned char>::const_iterator vi = vch.begin();
 while (vi != vch.end()) {
  res += (char) (*vi);
  vi++;
 }
 return res;
}

class Example
{
  cbuff label;
  Example(string labelIn)
  {
    SetLabel(labelIn);
  }
  IMPLEMENT_SERIALIZE
  (
    READWRITE(label);
  )
  void SetLabel(string labelIn)
  {
    label = vchFromString(labelIn);
  }
  string GetLabel()
  {
    return (stringFromVch(label));
  }
};
```