# Serializing a class that contains a string, to send it over a network through a socket?

Tags: c++, serialization, winsock, stdstring

I'm experimenting a little bit with the winsock library, by creating a pretty simple server-client connection. The client should send messages to the server, which should forward them to all the clients. Each client should only print a message if it's not the sender of the message itself.

In order to identify messages and serialize/deserialize them when sending them through the network, I created a Message class, that has among its members a std::string.

However, I'm having trouble with the serializing process.

To serialize, I use a struct SerializedMessage:

```
typedef struct {
    int         iMessageID;
    std::string strText;
} SerializedMessage;
```

I'd then like to create a new SerializedMessage* pointer, store data inside it and send it through the socket.
While I can easily save the id using the htonl() function, I don't know how to act with the string.

This is my Serialize method so far:

```
void* Message::Serialize()
{
    SerializedMessage* pSerializedMessage = new SerializedMessage();
    pSerializedMessage->iMessageID = htonl(m_iMessageID);
    //copying the text?
    return (void*)pSerializedMessage;
}
```

I've tried looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778806/serializing-a-class-with-a-pointer-in-c) and it should answer my question, but I'm a beginner and I'm not really understanding what the solution suggests me.

Would really appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: note - do not use `typedef struct` in `C++`, there is no need for it. Just use `struct`.

Comment: Got it. I actually come from C and in college they taught me that for readability it's better to define structs using typedefs. Is there any reason why it is suggested not to in cpp?

Comment: what part of the referenced answer(s) you do not understand ?

Comment: "*they taught me that for readability it's better to define structs using typedefs*" - it's not more readable. It's more *familiar* to people who come from `C`. It does not improve readability. Your college taught you wrong since they mistaken familiarity with simplicity/readability. It's dangerous to be unable to differentiate between those. Just use `struct` (or `class`) and forget the `typedef`.

Comment: in C having `struct S{...};` you cannot use _S_ alone and have to use _struct S_. In C++ having `struct S{...};` you can use _S_ directly

Comment: @Fureeish in college they only taught me about C; I am "bringing" this habit to C++, but since it's better not to, I'll make sure not to make this mistake.

Comment: @bruno I understood that, in the provided answer, the string is stored as `strlen:string` and then parsed, thus allocating a new string. Should I do the same thing (i.e.: save a string with that format, submit the serialized structure and then retrieve the string when deserializing)?

Comment: @Alex there is no parsing, the choice was to send the length of the string then the string, this is classical and allows at deserialization time to know the size before to read it. After you can do as you want, that way is not mandatory

Comment: Could I just add a field `int iSize` in the struct and do `pSerializedMessage->strText = m_strText;` and `pSerializedMessage->iSize = m_strText.size()`? How should I then procede to deserialize?

Comment: The problem is that `std::string` doesn't actually store the string in the object itself, so trying to directly send a struct containing it won't work. So you would figure out a format such that the receiver knows the length of the string, and then you would just send the actual string in binary. To deserialize, you either read in the length first and read that many bytes or you read until you find the terminator depending on how you're specifying the size.

Comment: You cannot send `std::string`, because it only stores pointer to data. You need to memcopy the string data into `char[]` of some size (and that's why length of actual string is needed as well).

Comment: Is there any way to do it using a support variable inside a struct? I've only seen example that write the string on (and retrieve it from) a file.

EDIT: so a char* to fill using memcpy and a size_t parameter would do the job?

Comment: You can't use a struct unless you fix the size of your string because the size of a struct is fixed.

Comment: What do you think the best way of serializing the Message class would be, if not a structure?

Comment: Use `std::string::data` to get a pointer to the contained data, then write that along with the size.

Comment: @Alex Define what a message will be at the byte level. Make sure to specify how message boundaries are indicated by the sender and found by the recipient. Then write code to fill in a message buffer from a structure and code to fill in a structure from a message buffer.

Answer (score 2):

The root cause of the problem is that text strings are variable length records.

There are three popular methods for serializing strings:  1) length followed by text, 2) text with terminator character and 3) Fixed length (maybe with padding).

### Length Followed by Text

Write the length of the text.
Write the text.

```
+-------------+  
| Text Length |  
+-------------+  
|             |
|    Text     |  
|             |
+-------------+
```

This technique is nice because you can *block read* the text; you know the length before reading (which also helps in allocating memory dynamically).

### Text With Terminator (Sentinel) Character

This is the definition of a C-Style string.

One issue with this method is that you don't know the length which makes allocating memory more tedious and you have to search until the terminator character is found (usually character by character).

### Fixed Length

Use a block size that is large enough to accommodate the largest text length, such as 4096.  This is popular with a lot of databases.  It is a performance / space trade-off.  The block is fast to load (read), because it is a fixed size.  It may waste space because there may be space not occupied by the text.